# Change of measure method

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $f(t)=t^2+1$,

Using change of measure method calculate

$$\mathbb{E}\Big(\exp \Big(\int_0^1f(t)dW_t \Big)\mathbb{1}_{\{\int_0^1f(t)dW_t\ge2\}}\Big)$$

Do you have any idea how to tackle this? I **don't expect** full solution, I will appreciate any hint...

---

Let

$$X_t := \int_0^t f(s)dW_s$$

Now $$Z_t:=\mathcal{E}(X)_t=\exp \left ( X_t - \frac{1}{2} [X]_t \right )=\exp \left ( \int_0^t f(s)dW_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f(s)^2ds \right )$$

Thus $$\mathbb{E}\Big(\exp \Big(\int_0^1f(t)dW_t \Big)\mathbb{1}_{\{\int_0^1f(t)dW_t\ge2\}}\Big)=\mathbb{E}\Big(Z_1\exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(s)^2ds\Big)\mathbb{1}_{\{\int_0^1f(t)dW_t\ge2\}}\Big)=
$$
$$
\exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(s)^2ds\Big)\mathbb{P}_Q \Big(\Big\{\int_0^1f(t)dW_t\ge2 \Big\}\Big)$$

Our new Wiener process:

$$ \tilde W_t =W_t -  \left [ W, X \right]_t=W_t-\int_0^tf(s)ds $$

So we have

$$\mathbb{P}_Q \Big(\Big\{\int_0^1f(t)dW_t\ge2 \Big\}\Big)=\mathbb{P}_Q \Big(\Big\{\int_0^1f(t)d\tilde W_t + \int_0^1 f(t)^2dt\ge2 \Big\}\Big)=\mathbb{P}_Q \Big(\Big\{\int_0^1f(t)d\tilde W_t \ge 0.1333 \Big\}\Big)$$

Comment: Is $(W_t)$ standard Brownian motion? You should make such assumption explicit.

Comment: Yes, it is standard wiener process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [Girsanov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem) with $X_t := \int_0^t f(t)dW_t$

Comment: I added something to my first post but I got stuck

Comment: Insert Z in your expectation, then use a probabilty change and a new brownian motion

Comment: Edited. Can you tell my if that is ok and what can I do next? $P_Q$ is our new probability measure

Comment: You got it, just replace $W$ by $\tilde{W}$ and use the law of a Wiener integral

Comment: Could you verify my last step please? Im very unsure about that transition...

Comment: It is correct, now what is the variance of $\int_0^1 f(t) d\tilde{W}_t$. The standard normal c.d.f. should appear in the final result.

Comment: Variance is equal to $\int_0^1f(t)^2 dt$? But how does it help me?